# Extension of a rational section of a projective bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, projective-geometry, projective-morphisms

Let us assume that we work over the complex field and let $X$ be a smooth projective variety and $\pi: P \to X$ a projective bundle (i.e. a fibration in projective spaces of constant dimension). Let $s : X \dashrightarrow P$ be a rational section. When does $s$ extend to a regular section?

As far as I can see, if the image $s(X)$ is contained (by taking the closure?) in a "horizontal" closed subset $W\subset P$ which is bijectively sent by $\pi$ to $X$, then I am done since $\pi$ is a bijective birational morphism $W \to X$ and by Zariski's main theorem it is an isomorphism. I am not sure though whether $s(X)$ can be completed in such a way, maybe over a curve or a surface it is ok. Is there another way to show this?

As someone has remarked here below, the case of curves is clear. I am interested in a case where $S$ is a smooth surface.

Comment: As you said, for curves it is alright, but for any higher dimension, it is in general false. That is, the closure of the image $s(X)$ does not map bijectively to $X$ and thus will not be a section. When you ask whether there is another way to show this, difficult to say without more specifics.

Comment: If $X$ is a smooth projective curve it is clearly ok just because any rational map $f:X\dashrightarrow Y$, where $Y$ is a projective variety, extends to a morphism.

Comment: sure for curves it is fine, yeah

Comment: There are a lot of results on extending rational sections, under various hypotheses. See for example Propositions 3.2 and 3.6 of [Daniel Litt's thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.07914) (although the latter does not cover your question).

Comment: OK I'll add the hypotheses I care about: X is a smooth surface

Comment: The surface case is already problematic: The blow up of $\mathbb{A}^2$ at the origin can be realized as the closure of section rational section of $\mathbb{A}^2\times \mathbb{P}^1\to \mathbb{A}^2$.

Comment: @Donu: yes, indeed! anyway my $S$ is projective.

Comment: Unfortunately, projectivity won't help with this.